# Qt - How to control the widget sizes in QLayout

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt

I am trying to put some spinboxes,line edits in a layout. But the size extends more than the neccesity. Below is the figure
[image]

Here I am adding a QScrollArea widget,and a QVBoxLayout into a QHBoxLayout. Then I am adding the line edits,spin boxes into the QVBoxLayout. But I want to reduce the width as 2/10 of the total width. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Why post a question that you're going to answer?

Comment: @g19fanatic I thought that some people may knew how to solve it. So that I posted it.Thereby I just tried to save my time( I am doing one project). In fact, I already tried that stretch factor. But, it didn't show the expected effect at that time. It shown only after I applied that factor on addWidget and addLayout . If you want me to remove my answer, no problem I will vote to delete

Comment: Again an annoying silent downvote. I think stack overflow should make something for these kind of downvoters who makes nothing but silent downvotes.And every body know that downvote has no meaning without the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy. It can be done by giving the stretching factor. That means you have to initiate the value when you use the functions

```
addWidget(widget,stretchfactor);
       or
addLayout(layout,stretchfactor);
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is not the best approach. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: You can also use the setStretch() method of the layout after you added the widgets.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, working with stretch factors is not the right solution, here. It's a bit "hackish". Stretch factors are useful e.g. when you have two widgets that both use as much space as possible, but not at a 50:50 rate.

Here, as I see it, you have two widgets (or groups of widgets), where one should only use as much space as it really needs and the other one should take the rest. That is what size policies are for. Set the horizontal policy of the left one to `Expanding` (or `MinimumExpanding` if you want to prevent scroll bars) and the right one to `Preferred`.

Comment: widget only having setSizePolicy. I couldn't find the same for QVBoxLayout

Comment: You can put widgets into another QWidget or QGroupBox

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with `void setSizeConstraint ( SizeConstraint )` and `minimumSize()` inherited methods.

[Read the doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qvboxlayout.html)

Comment: The above picture is not a maximized one, that is it's default size. And I want the widgets should be maximized, when the main widget is maximized . Also The layout's should keep the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at QSizePolicy. It may be usefull.